# GUI for R script - options

Tags: r, user-interface

I wish to build a simple GUI for my R script, what are the options (beside R shiny) I have and which one is the simplest to handle?

Thanks

Comment: What issue are you having with shiny? Have a look at [WebDevelopR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WebDevelopR/WebDevelopR.pdf).

Comment: No issues at all. I just do not want it as web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcltk is the easiest, as it's built into most R installations. [gWidgets2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets2/index.html) is theoretically more robust because it is GUI language-independent. tcltk also has abysmal documentation, while gWidgets2 can produce a Tcl/tk GUI and has actual documentation.

There used to be a project called SciViews that had lots of info about graphical user interfaces in R but the website seems to be down as of August 2014.

Finally, it's hard to offer more specific advice without more details on what you're trying to do.